# Which one is best? convert datatable to json or xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, datatable

I create two projects using dot net. I send some data from one project to another project. I already handled this using xml conversion. Now I think to convert this using json data. Which one is best?.

Comment: This question is likely to produce opinionated answers. I have voted to close. What I think is "best" isn't what others might think is "best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases， json is better. Because it has less redundant text and more efficient to parse. And what's more, is's much easier to parse json in javascript so that building a web app is much more convenient.

On the other hand, XML is more readable than json. That might be the only advantage of XML in this case.

Comment: Two projects in .NET, sending data between them, and yes, fact that JSON works better with JavaScript is very, very important :)

Answer (score 0):

XML is more verbose, but in the other hand is pretty easy to read.
JSON is simpler but not so good to read.
If you will not have humans looking the data, maybe using JSON would be a better idea. Since its smaller and will be less of a burden in your network (If that is a problem).
The other way you could evaluate, is looking on serialization speed, and that will depend a lot on the library you are using.